# create tables from S3 bucket file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

In my S3 bucket I have several files with different schemas.

```
s3://folder/file1.csv
s3://folder/file2.csv
s3://folder/file3.csv
s3://folder/file4.csv
```

All files contain fields I need, but number of columns differs.

I try to do this for one of the file, but the created table remains empty

```
CREATE  EXTERNAL TABLE test1 (
app_id string,
app_version string
)
row format delimited fields terminated by  ','
 LOCATION 's3://folder/file4.csv';


MSCK REPAIR TABLE test1;
```

Can I create 3 tables from these files? Or I can put fields I need from all files in one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define a **file** as a `LOCATION` for Amazon Athena. It will result in this error message:

> Can't make directory for path 's3://my-bucket/foo.csv' since it is a file

You should put each file in a separate folder and then set the `LOCATION` to the folder. All files in that folder (even if it is just one file) will be scanned for each query.

Also, there is no need to call `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` unless it contains partitions.

By the way, this line:

```
LOCATION 's3://folder/file4.csv'
```

should also specify the bucket name:

```
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/folder/file4.csv'
```

Comment: Thank you!
So, if schemas are slightly different I should put them in separate folders,right? Cause all files contain fields I need, but the number of columns in each scheama are not equal

Comment: Correct. Each file needs a separate `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` command and a separate location for the file(s) that contribute data to that table. (A folder can contain multiple files, but they must all be the same format and will all provide data to the same table.)